# Display local variable with DisplayFor?

Tags: .net, razor, model-view-controller

I've defined Shared/DisplayTemplates/decimal.cshtml
with custom formatting.

I'm aware that whis works with @Html.DisplayFor,

but how to format local variable defined in Razor view? For example @{ decimal d=5; }
It seems that you cannot display local variable with DisplayFor..

Comment: `DisplayFor` is for use with your model, yo can't do that.

Comment: Reading your question more closely, Razor uses reflection to determine what display template to use, so if you want to use `DisplayFor` in order to use a template you will likely need to add a property to your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Html.DisplayFor(x=>name); this the syntax for using DisplayFor. if u want to show local variable then simply place local vaiable @Html.DisplayFor(d);

Comment: Tried that, got: Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor<TModel,TValue>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TValue>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @Ljudevit You can't use `DisplayFor` with a local variable since it uses reflection.

Comment: @D Stanley, actually It works *almost* as Hashmi said: @Html.DisplayFor(x => d); where d is my local variable and it uses Display format. That way I can have decimal format at one place.